# How to update DocsList to DriveApp in my code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

My script that generates a pdf document from a template within Google Drive and emails it to a recipient based on columns in a spreadsheet stopped working today due to the depreciation of DocsList. See here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

I have tried updating following this guide https://developers.google.com/drive/web/migration to update all instances of DocsList with DriveApp, but I cannot get it to work. Could somebody please help me update this script to work properly? I have 6 instances of "DocsList" in this script, and I was able to update some of them properly but others such as "addFile" seem to require a different format. Even after trying to simply find and replace "DocsList" with "DriveApp" I get the following Error Message:

" TypeError: Cannot find function addFile in object ProofOfCredit_CNZDTVR44N.pdf. (line 45, file "ProofOfCreditCode")"

I would appreciate any advice and help, as this depreciation broke 5 of my scripts which are pretty much identical to this one.

```
var docTemplate = "1JAPmsrPRrRwXCVAli229C5J7Kr4xaOnfO2rmGqvYyhU"; 
var docName     = "ProofOfCredit";

function onFormSubmit(e) {
   var first_name = e.values[1];
   var last_name = e.values[2];
   var customer_email = e.values[3];
   var order_number = e.values[4];
   var brand = e.values[5];
   var amount = e.values[6];
   var date_of_credit = e.values[7];
   var auth_code = e.values[8];
   var last_4 = e.values[9];
   var request_id = e.values[10];
   var rep_name = e.values[11];
   var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
                .makeCopy(docName+'_'+order_number)
                .getId();   

   var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
   var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

   copyBody.replaceText('keyFirst', first_name);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyLast', last_name);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyBrand', brand);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyAmount', amount);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyCreditdate', date_of_credit);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyAuth', auth_code);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyRep', rep_name);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyOrder', order_number);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyCClast4', last_4);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyRequestID', request_id);
   var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"); 
   copyBody.replaceText('keyTodaysDate', todaysDate);

   copyDoc.saveAndClose();

   var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
   var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Proof of Credit');
   var movefile = DocsList.createFile(pdf);
   movefile.addToFolder(folder);
   movefile.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
   var subject = "Proof of Credit regarding Order Number: " + order_number;
   var body    = "Hello " + first_name + " " + last_name + "," + "<br /><br />" 
   + "Thank you for calling " + brand + " Support. The attached document contains information " 
   + "for you to reference related to the credits we have issued back to your original form of payment." + "<br /><br />" 
   + "If you have any further questions or require additional assistance please let us know." + "<br /><br />" 
   + "Regards," + "<br /><br />" 
   + rep_name + ", Payments Department" + "<br />" 
   + "test@test.com";
   var cc = "test@test.com";
   MailApp.sendEmail(customer_email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf, cc: cc}); 
   DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: This is the original code without having replaced the string "DocsList" with "DriveApp", as this did not work (nor did I expect it to but I figured it was worth a try)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many of the `DriveApp` methods are identical to `DocsList`.  So, in many cases, you can simply replace `DocsList` with `DriveApp`.

Problems arise with the old `getFolder()` method.

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Name of your folder');
```

In this case, simply replacing `DocsList` with `DriveApp` will give you a problem.  There is no `getFolder()` method for `DriveApp`.  In Google Drive,  you can have multiple files and folders with identical names (But different ID's).  The old `DocsList`, `getFolder()` method did not take this situation into account.  With `DriveApp`, you can still search for a folder by name, but the return is a `Folder Iterator`.  With `DriveApp` the method name for getting a folder by name is very slightly different; it's "folders", with an "s" on the end.  `getFoldersByName(name)` Plural, not singular.  So, even though 98% of the time, getting folders by name will result in only one folder, you still need process the `Folder Iterator`. You don't *need* to loop through the folder iterator.  You can just get the first folder.  Just use the `next()` method without using a programming loop.

[Folder Iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)

So, I suggest that you *do* just replace `DocsList` with `DriveApp` except in the case of getting a folder by name.  Read the documentation, and fix that line of code, then run it.  If you get an error, **VIEW** the **EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT**, and it will probably tell you what line of code failed.  If you still need help, always post what line of code failed.

Also, there is no `addToFolder()` method of the new DriveApp Folder class.

[Folder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)

You will need to change that to:

```
folder.addFile(moveFile);
```

[addFile() Method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File))

Comment: Thank you Sandy. I did as you suggested and replaced all strings of "DocsList" with "DriveApp". I had to change 




var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Proof of Credit'); to 




var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3nrCN8N5OBceFQ5WGVVLWVoNjQ');


but I am still getting the following error: 4/21/15 1:12 PM onFormSubmit TypeError: Cannot find function addToFolder in object ProofOfCredit_CNZDTVR44N.pdf. (line 45, file "ProofOfCreditCode")

Comment: Thank you! I think I was able to figure it out just as you replied. I replaced var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
   var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Proof of Credit');
   var movefile = DocsList.createFile(pdf);
   movefile.addToFolder(folder);
   movefile.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder()); with  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
   var theblob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3nrCN8N5OBceFQ5WGVVLWVoNjQ');
   var movefile = folder.createFile(theblob); and it seems to be working.

Answer (score -1):

There is no method for "adding to folder" for a File object in DriveApp. Instead, you need to get the folder (which it looks like you store in var folder), and then use the Folder object to add a file. It would look something like this:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(string id);
var movefile = DocsList.createFile(pdf);
folder.addFile(moveFile);
```

You can use Folder objects to add a file to the Folder, but DriveApp has no method for File objects to add themselves to a folder.

Comment: Did you intend to still have a deprecated `DocsList` method call in your answer?