# Error of duplication in root drive with google script while copying a file from one folder to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So, I'm trying to copy a file which is updated automatically in my computer in a folder.
Thing is that every time the script runs, it copies the file in the selected folder but also creates a duplication in the root folder despite root isn't referred in the whole script

```js
function moveFiles() {

  var olderfiles = DriveApp.getFolderById("idfromdestinyfolder").getFiles(); 
  while (olderfiles.hasNext()) {

    var olderfile = olderfiles.next();
    var pull = DriveApp.getFolderById("idfromdestinyfolder");
    pull.removeFile(olderfile)
  }

  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("idfromstartingfolder").getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("idfromdestinyfolder");
    file.makeCopy("nameofthefile",destination);
  }
}
```

The first part olderfiles checks if a file exist in the destiny, and if exists, it removes it.
The second part copies the file from the starting folder to destination.

Thing is, every time it runs, it creates a copy in root which should not happen.
Is the first time I'm using google script

Comment: There is no method `removeFile` in [class  Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)

Comment: @Cooper It's in the list of deprecated methods. So it exists, but they shouldn't use it in new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question

> ... it copies the file in the selected folder but also creates a duplication in the root folder despite root isn't referred in the whole script

The problem might be caused by the use of Class [Folder.removeFile(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder). Pleaser bear in mind that  it's a deprecated method, the docs instructs to use [Folder.moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination) instead.

If you are looking to send the file to the trash, then use [Class File.setTrashed(true)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setTrashed(Boolean))

Related

- [Permanently delete file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25749906/1595451)
- [Delete or Trash specific file in Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30709372/1595451)

Comment: Deprecated methods should still work. What destination should they move to if they want to remove the file? Is there a standard Trash folder for this?

Comment: @Barmar Use Class File.setTrashed(true) (answer edited)

Comment: It worked, changed the pull directly by setTrashed and didn't generate a copy.
var file2 = olderfile.next();
    file2.setTrashed(true)

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this makeCopy()

```
function makeCopy() {
  var folderid = "folderid";
  var fileid = "fileid";
  var folder = Drive.Files.get(folderid, { "supportsAllDrives": true });
  var newFile = { "fileId": fileid, "parents": [folder] };
  var args = { "resource": { "parents": [folder], "title": "new Title" }, "supportsAllDrives": true };
  Drive.Files.copy(newFile, fileid, args);
}
```